# How to add own round() mode (round down if < x.x7, round up if >= x.x7)

Tags: php

I'm curious if there is a possibility to set an own [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) mode. `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` and `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` doesn't fit my needs, because numbers should rounded down if the decimals are < x.x7 and rounded up if the decimals are >= x.x7.

```
123.6691243 --> 123.6
123.671     --> 123.7
123.109043  --> 123.1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: No, there isn't this option in the built-in round() function, which is designed to support the common cases, not every single unique edge case. you'd need to write your own function to do this

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
round(x - .02)
```